# Getting scores for gamecenter from another class in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, game-center

So basically I have a simple game that I created with Swift. The problem now is that my "score" integer variable that I need to update the highscore for gamecenter is in another class in a .swift file that I created. How can I grab the score variable from that class into my `gameviewcontroller.swift` where all my gamecenter code is located at? Thanks so much everyone! :)

**Edit:**

My code is like this. I have another swift file with a new class with my "score" variable.

```
class scoreClass: SKLabelNode {

    var number:Int = 0

    init(digit: Int) {

        super.init()

        fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        fontName = "Alpha Taurus Pro"
        fontSize = 45.0

        number = digit
        text = "\(digit)"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func increment() {

        number++
        text = "\(number)"
    }

    func setTo(digit: Int) {

        self.number = digit
        text = "\(self.number)"
    }
}
```

The variable is basically my score. In my gamescene I call the functions in this class that updates the score. But my gamecenter code is all in gameviewcontroller. I have tried calling the variable from this class but its always just 0 since the original variable is zero.

Comment: does anyone know how this can work? :(

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `NSNotificationCenter` and `NSNotification` APIs. You may make your GameViewController listen to a custom notification and let your score variable code post the notification upon change of the score.

Comment: I am not sure that I know what you are saying. Can you please expand? :)

Comment: I suggest you to put your code in the answer so that I can help you more specifically.

Comment: have any suggestions??